# How to plot multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-science

I have dataframe `total_year`, which contains three columns (`year`, `action`, `comedy`).

[image]

How can I plot two columns (`action` and `comedy`) on y-axis?
My code plots only one:

```
total_year[-15:].plot(x='year', y='action', figsize=(10,5), grid=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Pandas.DataFrame.plot()` per default uses index for plotting `X` axis, all other **numeric** columns will be used as `Y` values.

So setting `year` column as index will do the trick:

```
total_year.set_index('year').plot(figsize=(10,5), grid=True)
```

Answer (score 54):

Several column names may be provided to the `y` argument of the pandas plotting function. Those should be specified in a `list`, as follows.

```
df.plot(x="year", y=["action", "comedy"])
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [1914,1915,1916,1919,1920],
                   "action" : [2.6,3.4,3.25,2.8,1.75],
                   "comedy" : [2.5,2.9,3.0,3.3,3.4] })
df.plot(x="year", y=["action", "comedy"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- When using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), it's only necessary to specify a column to the `x` parameter.

  - The caveat is, the rest of the columns with `numeric` values will be used for `y`.
  - The following code contains extra columns to demonstrate. Note, `'date'` is left as a `string`. However, if `'date'` is converted to a `datetime` `dtype`, the plot API will also plot the `'date'` column on the y-axis.
- If the dataframe includes many columns, some of which should not be plotted, then specify the `y` parameter as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47791257/7758804), but if the dataframe contains only columns to be plotted, then specify only the `x` parameter.
- **In cases where the index is to be used as the x-axis, then it is not necessary to specify `x=`.**

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
data = {'year': [1914, 1915, 1916, 1919, 1920],
        'action': [2.67, 3.43, 3.26, 2.82, 1.75],
        'comedy': [2.53, 2.93, 3.02, 3.37, 3.45],
        'test1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        'date': ['1914-01-01', '1915-01-01', '1916-01-01', '1919-01-01', '1920-01-01']}

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df)
   year  action  comedy test1        date
0  1914    2.67    2.53     a  1914-01-01
1  1915    3.43    2.93     b  1915-01-01
2  1916    3.26    3.02     c  1916-01-01
3  1919    2.82    3.37     d  1919-01-01
4  1920    1.75    3.45     e  1920-01-01

# plot the dataframe
df.plot(x='year', figsize=(10, 5), grid=True)
```

[image]