# How to have multiple dependent variables inside plot()?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I don't know how to ask this question. Basically, I am reading through an Excel file and I have multiple dependent variables that I want to graph. I want to have multiple lines graph but I can't seem to figure it out how to do it.

```
    df = pd.read_excel(workbook1)
    #print(df.head())
    values = df[['Tolerance', 'BM Iteration', 'MM Iteration', 'NM Iteration', 'SM Iteration']]

    ax = values.plot(x='Tolerance', y1='BM Iteration', y2= 'MM Iteration', y3 = 'SM Iteration')

    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    #ax.get_legend().remove()
    ax.set_title('Something', fontsize=14)
    plt. xlabel('x-axis', fontsize=14)
    plt. ylabel('y-axis', fontsize=14)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: `values.plot(x='Tolerance')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot multiple pandas columns on the y-axis of line graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47775220/7758804)