# Line plot with all column

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I want to plot (line plot) the trend of all my coins. See my data frame below:

```
                   #MetaHash_24h Volume  0x_24h Volume  1inch_24h Volume  
Time                                                                      
14:00 16/03/2021              196876.0    162052086.0       279895846.0   
14:02 16/03/2021              271687.0    150463819.0       281510814.0
```

Time is the index and each column is one coin. The plot I want is time in X-axes and money in y-axes. I have found something similar in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775220/how-to-plot-multiple-pandas-columns-on-the-y-axis-of-line-graph) but with the difference that I have my x-axes in the index and I cannot specify the y-axis writing the headers because my data frame has 800 columns.

Comment: what does `df.plot()` do for your? Although you should certainly think twice about plotting 800 lines :-).

Comment: ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting when the default backend "matplotlib" is selected.

I want to see how the plot looks before reducing some of then

Comment: then `pip install matplotlib` or `conda install matplotlib`